# How can I upgrade the "find" command to the latest version?

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade

I got [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/713255/168855) answer for [Is it possible to chain two consecutive find commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713249/is-it-possible-to-chain-two-consecutive-find-commands) last year.

Today I wanted to test the latest recommendation to pipe two `find` commands together.

```
find ... -print0 | find -files0-from - ...
```

To my surprise it did not work and I got this error:

> find: unknown predicate `-files0-from'

I checked the `file` version using `file --version` and it was `find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0`

This confuses me, as I use the **Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS** and run `apt update && apt upgrade` every day.

So, how can I update my `find` command to the latest version?

Comment: If you were using the *latest* Ubuntu release, you'd be using `4.9.0-3ubuntu1`, but you're two releases behind that (ie. 22.04, 22.10 then 23.04)  fyi: https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/f/findutils/findutils_4.9.0-5/changelog show changes to the version on my Ubuntu *mantic* system; but it's useful to contrast your older version up to *latest* available in Ubuntu repositories...

Comment: Install Ubuntu 22.10 or 23.04. coreutils don't get upgraded.

Comment: @Rinzwind, [Ubuntu 22.10 is EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/) thus not a great idea; 23.04 the only *fully supported* option

Comment: @guiverc IMHO the linked answer does not answer this question. @Rinzwind's remark that `coreutils don't get upgraded` seems to me the real answer.

Comment: @guiverc, then we can't update `find` individually? We are locked to the entire GNU?

Comment: Fair enough @Jos, to me it's the side effect of Ubuntu being a *stable release* system (like Debian upstream of Ubuntu), which I see covered in *psusi's* answer in the duplicate myself...

Comment: You can install findutils from Ubuntu 23.04 in Ubuntu 22.04 using this command: `wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/findutils/findutils_4.9.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb && sudo apt install ./findutils_4.9.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb` If you want to accept this comment as an answer I'll reopen this question and post it as an answer so that you can accept it. If not simply ignore this comment.

Comment: @karel, that's exactly what I was searching for. Thank you. Please do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install findutils from Ubuntu 23.04 in Ubuntu 22.04 using these commands:

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/findutils/findutils_4.9.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
sudo apt install ./findutils_4.9.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Just be aware that when manually installing software from other sources (including later Ubuntu releases, Debian etc.) you might break some dependencies at a later stage. Use with caution.